# On Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS sound in from microphone or usb doesn't reach the speakers

Tags: sound, usb

I am trying to record and save some old vinyl records on my PC. I have put a digital adaptor in line from the turntable to the USB port but even though the sound signal appears on settings-sound it doesn't come out of the speakers.

Any help?

Comment: Please include more details like debug info, and etc. More info here on how to write a [good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask).